# Генерация множеств в Python 3.*

Tags: python

Читаю книгу М. Лутца *[Изучаем Python](http://www.books.ru/books/izuchaem-python-4-e-izdanie-fail-pdf-864712/)*. На 584 странице вижу примеры генераторов:

1 (генератор списков):

```
>>> [x * x for x in range(10)]
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
```

2 (генератор множеств):

```
>>> {x * x for x in range(10)}
{0, 1, 4, 81, 64, 9, 16, 49, 25, 36}
```

3 (генератор словарей):

```
>>> {x: x * x for x in range(10)}
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 4, 3: 9, 4: 16, 5: 25, 6: 36, 7: 49, 8: 64, 9: 81}
```

Во всех трех примерах одно и то же выражение *x * x*. Генерируемая очередность понятна в первом и третьем случаях, но не во втором. Ощущение, что 64 и 81 здесь не на своих местах. Тем не менее, что это за последовательность?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Во втором случае - это множество. А в нем порядок элементов не определенный. Более того, в множестве нельзя сказать "дайте второй элемент" или "первые два", но можно сказать "дайте все больше 4" или "общие элементы в двух множествах". Из-за того, что в них нет "оффициальной" упорядоченности, они позволяют делать указанные вещи значительно быстрее, чем вручную на списках/массивах.

Внутри они конечно упорядочены как то, но на этот порядок нельзя полагаться - это внутренние детали.

Comment: кстати, это к словарям тоже относиться